# Sitecore Cortex Tagging for Predefined Tags

Tags: cortex

I am using Sitecore 10.2 and also using [Sitecore Cortex Content Tagging](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/tag-content-using-sitecore-cortex-content-tagging.html). I have different tag which is being created in Sitecore. I want to tag content that is available in tags only, I don't want to create new tags. I did not find any document related to this. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box setting that will allow to disable creation of new tags.

However, you can create a custom taxonomy provider for Sitecore Content Tagging and implement your own logic in the `CreateTags` method or simply override the method `CreateTag` of `DefaultTaxonomyProvider`:

```
public class CustomTaxonomyProvider : DefaultTaxonomyProvider
{ 
    protected override ID CreateTag(TagData data)
    {
        //your logic for creating or skipping a tag
        return tagId;
    }
}
```

Then your custom taxonomy provider can be registered in the config to be used in Content Tagging functionality:

```
<contentTagging>
    <providers>
        <taxonomy>
            <add name="CustomTaxonomyProvider" type="Namespace.CustomTaxonomyProvider, AssemblyName" />
        </taxonomy>
    </providers>
</contentTagging>
```

Sitecore documentation for custom Content Tagging providers can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/build-a-custom-taxonomy-provider-for-sitecore-content-tagging.html).

Comment: Thanks, Anna for your response. I understand that I can restrict the tag to not be created in Sitecore but  I want to get only the taxonomy that is available in Sitecore. Currently, in IDiscoveryProvider, the cortex will return some taxonomy that may be not in my Sitecore. Suppose I have taxonomy A, B, C in Sitecore and Cortex is returning D, E then in this case it will not be useful for me. I want to pass A,B, C to Cortex, and Cortex can return relevant taxonomy may be B,C

Comment: @SwatiGupta thanks for clarification. I had another look at the Open Calais API that Sitecore uses and it does not have any parameter to include/exclude specific tags in the API response https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/api-catalog/open-perm-id/intelligent-tagging-restful-api/documentation. You can try implementing a custom discovery provider (`IDiscoveryProvider`) and take only required tags from the API response (`GetTags`). I know it won't return tags A, B or C if Open Calais thinks there are only D and E in the provided content, but hopefully it will help you filter out unnecessary tags

Comment: Thanks, @Anna, I think OpenCalais will not fit in my requirement :)